# What is Redis ValueOperations?

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-data

What is Redis Value operations in Spring boot?
Is it like we can directly store Key-value pair in Redis database without creating the entity and stuff just by using `RedisTemplate<String, Object>` ?
Also, if we use `ValueOperations` how will it impact the performance?

Answer (score 4):

When using Redis, you should think about what data format/datatype suits your needs best, similar to what you would do when coding in any general programming language. All those operations, `ValueOperations, ListOperations, SetOperations, HashOperations, StreamOperations` are the support provided for interacting with the mentioned datatypes. They are provided by the `RedisTemplate`.

When you are using `ValueOperations`, you are more or less treating your whole Redis instance as a giant hash map. For example, you can store entries in Redis like `current_user = "John Doe"`. However, you can also do something silly such as keeping a string representation of a huge hashmap against a key, `top_users = <huge_string_representing_a_hash_map>` when thinking from the perspective of the second case, what if you want to get the value for one key in the mentioned hash map. Then, the task becomes more or less impossible without transferring the whole hash map in RAM. Yet, if you have used Redis Hashes and `HashOperations` that would have been a more trivial task.

Going back to your question, if you want to store a simple object using ValueOperations. That wouldn't degrade the performance. In contrast, if you are moving huge maps around, you'll utilise a lot of your network bandwidth and RAM capacity.

In summary, choose your Redist data types carefully to suit your needs.
https://redis.io/topics/data-types

Comment: Check this link as well, https://stackabuse.com/spring-boot-with-redis-hashoperations-crud-functionality/